# How well does Programming Clojure work on the Kindle?

Tags: clojure, kindle

[Programming Clojure](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/programming-clojure) is currently available only in electronic form.  I see it's available in .mobi format for the Kindle.  My question is, how well does this work?  I know some programming books can lose the formatting of the code on the Kindle.  Has anyone tried this?  Does this version work well?

Comment: I just got an email today that the paper copy is coming in a few weeks, for those who pre-ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 3 books from the Pragmatic guys on my Kindle 2 right now and they render wonderfully.

Although I'm upgrading to the Kindle DX purely for the native PDF reading functionality.  I really can't wait.

Comment: My kindle finally arrived.  I concur.  It renders very well.

Comment: My nook doesn't wrap PRE content onto the next line. I suppose the Kindle does?

Answer (score 1):

The big thing is that they use a fair bit of color in the Prag books; the Kindle of course doesn't handle that.  But if you buy the e-book format, you get PDF, .mobi and one other I forget.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to take the plunge.  I purchased the eBook in beta.  Doing so allows me to download all 3 variants (pdf, epub, and mobi).  I don't have a Kindle (yet--it's in the mail) but I did load the mobi version in the Mobipocket reader on Windows.  The code all appears to be formatted correctly which was my worry.  the illustrations all seem intact.  I've seen poorly formatted programming books, but this doesn't appear to be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have an iRex Iliad and use pdfs on it (from apress mostly) and have no problems at all...